# Initiating a connection between two browser windows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, window

I understand that if one window opens another that the opened window the return value of `.open(path)`.

I also get that the child window can access the parent through `window.opener`.

However, in the event that the parent has since been closed, and another window (or tab) from the same domain has been opened, is there any way to grant access from one window to another in a horizontal fashion? Maybe by passing a reference through a cookie or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.  If you don't have a reference to the window there's no way to get it.  You can still send messages to another tab, however, via HTML5's localStorage events

Answer (score 0):

If you in the parent have

```
window.name="myParentWindow"
```

the child can do

```
var parentHandle = (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) ? window.opener :
     window.open("","myParentWindow");
```